# Access SQL Server 2014 from Oracle database 12c

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2014, oracle12c

How can I access or connect to Sql Server 2014 Enterprise from Oracle 12c Enterprise.

I want to connect so that I can run DML queries on SQL Server 2014 tables, EXECUTE procedures and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from Oracle to SQL Server is called a "Database Link"

Going from SQL Server to Oracle uses a "Linked Server".

Somebody has explained it over at Stack Exchange.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15708/how-to-create-oracle-linked-server-in-oracle-server-itself

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Oracle's [Heterogeneous Connectivity](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/nav/portal_15.htm#heterogeneous_connectivity) documentation.  There's a guide for each of several different remote data sources.  You'll want to focus on the ones for [ODBC](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODBCU/toc.htm) or [SQL Server](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/GMSWN/toc.htm).  If I remember correctly the Heterogeneous database gateway for ODBC is included with standard database licensing, but Heterogeneous database gateway for SQL Server requires additional licensing.

Comment: What is the difference between the "_Heterogeneous database gateway for ODBC_" and _"Heterogeneous database gateway for SQL Server"_?

Comment: The one for ODBC uses ODBC drivers and can therefore connect to any DB for which you can get ODBC drivers, whereas the one specifically for SQL Server uses native SQL Server protocols, and is specific to just SQL Server, but it provides better functionality than the ODBC connectivity.  I believe there are some features that don't work well or at all over ODBC that will work correctly using the native SQL Server connection.  As one example I think the ODBC drivers have issues with Memo fields in SQL Server, and there may be other shortcomings as well.